# Basic Array[] Tree Data-Structure in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is a homework question, so I'm not looking for a complete code answer.

I have been given a class Dog

```
package lab12;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Dog implements Serializable{

    public Dog[] children;
    public String name;

    public Dog(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

And a datafile that contains a root dog Spot that has its children stored in an array. I need to write code that can open the datafile, and then step through the tree data structure to see if an input name is a descendant of the root (Spot).

I am pretty confident I can open the datafile. I am struggling with the syntax of creating nodes that have an array as the link. Our textbook covers only binary trees, which either link to left or right, but not to a variable number of links. I found an example of a generic one that uses a List approach.

```
public class Tree<T> 
{
    private Node<T> root;

    public static class Node<T> 
    {
        private T data;
        private Node<T> parent;
        private List<Node<T>> children;
    }

    public Tree(T rootData) 
    {
        root = new Node<T>();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.children = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }
}
```

Since I have to use the datafile I can't change the structure of the Node to anything other than storing the children in a Dog[]. I can't find an example of a node class using a basic array to store the children and I can't figure out the syntax for doing this. I think it would help my understanding to see it without generics before I try to learn it with.

Here's my code so far:

```
package lab12;

public class DogTree 
{
    //Start Inner Class
    private static class Node
    {
        private String name;
        private Node parent;
        private Node Dog[] children; //This is where I'm confused
    }
    //End Inner Class

    private Node root;

    public DogTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isDescendant(String name)
    {
        return isInSubtree(name, root);
    }

    private static boolean isInSubtree(String name, Node subTreeRoot)
    {
        if(subTreeRoot == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(subTreeRoot.name.equals(name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //This is where my confusion on the 
            //node design causes implementation problems
            return isInSubtree(name, subTreeRoot.children); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to design an additional DogTree class? You already have a tree structure with the Dog class, since a Dog has an array of children, where each child is itself a Dog having an array of children, where each child ...

Comment: This might help - it's more than you need - but pick the bits that you want. You should be able to easily modify recurseDepth to do your search. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/TreeNode.htm

Comment: Our text always makes a separate class for node/list setup from the entry class. That said I only did so because I'm trying to start from somewhere familiar.

Comment: Here's a few to pick the one you like ... Google is your friend ... http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Tree.htm

Comment: Thanks xagyg and JB Nizet, I'm working on implementing parts of the solutions you've given me. I'll let you know if I hit other obstacles.

Comment: Took awhile, but figured it out. Wish I knew how to give you credit somehow, but thanks JB Nizet, your comment helped me figured this out the most.

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate over the array of children.

```
private static boolean isInSubtree(String name, Node subTreeRoot)
    {
        if(subTreeRoot == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(subTreeRoot.name.equals(name))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
           for( int i = 0; i< subTreeRoot.children.length();i++)
             if(isInSubtree(name, subTreeRoot.children[i]))
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between array and array list in those algorithms is that you have limited capacity for arrays and you need to handle the allocation of items (puppies);

You should not focus on the generic if the task is to learn the array. Generic allow you to define a template for common functionality of objects. It is better to change the implementation when is done into generic than starting from them to solve concrete issue.

What you have now is the class like this:

```
class Dog {

    private String name;
    private Dog[] puppies

    public Dog(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

What you can do is to add the specific method to it that will perform some action.

```
class Dog {

    private final String name;
    private final Dog[] puppies = new Dog[20]; //We create 20 slots for puppies to fill
    private int  puppiesCount = 0;

    public Dog(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public addPuppie(Dog puppie) {
      this.puppies[puppiesCount] = puppie; //We assign the puppie to this Dog puppies.
      this.puppiesCount = puppiesCount + 1; //We increment the count of puppies
    }

    public Dog[] getPuppies() {
      return Arrays.copyOf(puppies, puppiesCount); 
    }

    public boolean isMyPuppie(Dog puppie) {

        for(int = 0; i < puppiesCount; i++) {

          if(puppies[i] == puppie) { //We compare the object references to state that are equal
             return true;
          }

        }

      return false;
    }
}
```

How this transfer into a tree.

As every object has an array of is self it is possible to nest them.

```
Dog max = new Dog("Max");

Dog tom = new Dog("Tom"); //childOfRoot;

Dog barry = new Dog("Barry);"// child of Tom
```

To create a tree you need to do something like this.

```
tom.addPuppie(barry); // We assign barry to tom
max.addPuppie(tom); // we assign tom to max.
```

This concept should be extended with deep search where you need to introduce a recurrency search and a relation from child to parent could be added.